# Is it possible for a citizen (but non-resident) to buy and insure an RV/Camper Van in Europe?

Tags: europe, automobiles, insurance

I have Italian citizenship but my "residence" is in Canada. It's where my driver's licence is based. I'm however planning to return to Europe on a long-term basis and am considering buying an *recreational vehicle* (RV) / Camper Van there. Though I information about any vehicle ownership would be similar. When I'm there, I won't have a permanent address in any country.

Is it possible to buy a vehicle in Europe without an address there? What about insurance?

I have heard of services (several based in Netherlands) that will "rent to own" you an RV that they own and with it comes insurance cover. Not sure how that service works. I'd like to buy a different RV and own it outright.

Can I do it? If not, is it possible to buy a vehicle with a friend who is a resident and still get insurance cover for myself? Any other way of doing it?

Comment: What is a 'RV'?

Comment: @Mark RV - recreational vehicle, sometimes 'camper van'

Comment: This might be better on the Expatriates stack.

Comment: @mdewey Since the OP is **not** a resident in Europe, this is doubtfull.